# Why do the author use a tilde before file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tilde

I'm learning node and express programming and find a very good example at: https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo

But I find a line and not fully understand.

```
// Bootstrap models
var models_path = __dirname + '/app/models';
fs.readdirSync(models_path).forEach(function (file) {
    if (~file.indexOf('.js')) require(models_path + '/' + file)
})
```

On the 4th line before file, there is a tilde( ~ )operator. I consult the javascript book, and it just says it's a bitwise NOT.

Why author use tilde here? 
If not using tilde, can I have other way to express the same thing?

Thank you!

Comment: `indexOf()` will return `-1`, bit negation `-1` is `0`. Shorter (but iMO less clear) than `== -1`.

Comment: @Adriano this should be an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tilde is the [bitwise not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7E_%28Bitwise_NOT%29). The `.indexOf()` method returns the index of the found match in a string (or in an array) or `-1` if the substring was not found.

Because `0 == false` tilde may be used to transform `-1` in `0` and viceversa:

```
> ~1
-2
> ~0
-1
> ~-1
0
```

`~file.indexOf('.js')` is equivalent to `file.indexOf('.js') === -1` or `file.indexOf('.js') < 0`. The last two examples are more clear to understand that the first one.

Answer (score 1):

This statement help include only .js files into project. We can replace this statment with, this expression

```
 if (file.indexOf('.js') !== -1) require(models_path + '/' + file)
```

for your example https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo let's see
we have 2 files into /app/models/ : article.js and user.js

for acticle.js

```
if (~('acticle.js'.indexOf('.js'))) // -8 TRUE
if ('acticle.js'.indexOf('.js')) // 7   TRUE
```

for user.js

```
if (~('user.js'.indexOf('.js'))) // -5 TRUE
if ('user.js'.indexOf('.js')) // 4   TRUE
```

And in our case this values is equieal to TRUE, and this files will be included.

this statment ~file.indexOf('.js') solve problem when we have file without name like '.js'

```
if ('.js'.indexOf('.js')) // 0 FALSE but file exists and have .js extension
if (~('.js'.indexOf('.js'))) // -1 TRUE
```

As you can see. It will be included into project.

Comment: Shouldn't the assignments be expressions?